# Using the ttk.Separator with .place method

Tags: tkinter

I've created a detailed GUI which uses the .place method to organise all the widgets into the correct locations.  It's all working a treat and looks good.  I want to add a 'ttk.separator' to the GUI but it only displays a single pixel.  After hours of searching the only answer I have is that you cannot use this separator with the .place method, you need the 'sticky' and '.grid()' methods.  I know you can't mix .grid and .place, so I am stuck.

I want to keep using the .place method (I like the precision of it) but it seems if I do then the separator is out of the window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `place` geometry manager has options to set the width and height of a widget in either relative or absolute terms.

For example, to have a separator that starts at the left edge and continues to the right edge, just use `relwidth=1.0`. That says to make the widget 100% of the width of the parent.

From the official tk documentation (height options are identical, except they obviously affect the height rather than the width):

**-relwidth *size***

*Size* specifies the width for window. In this case the width is specified as a floating-point number relative to the width of the master: 0.5 means window will be half as wide as the master, 1.0 means window will have the same width as the master, and so on. If both -width and -relwidth are specified for a slave, their values are summed. For example, -relwidth 1.0 -width 5 makes the slave 5 pixels wider than the master.

**-width *size***

*Size* specifies the width for window in screen units (i.e. any of the forms accepted by Tk_GetPixels). The width will be the outer width of window including its border, if any. If size is an empty string, or if no -width or -relwidth option is specified, then the width requested internally by the window will be used.

Comment: Bryan, thank you very much that worked a treat and the answer was so simple.